# query_posts ignores the argument

Tags: loop, query-posts

The query_posts totally ignores the day argument. I'm trying this:

```
$day = date('j');
query_posts('day='.$day);

if (have_posts()):
   while (have_posts()): the_post();
   //show posts
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Never use query_posts, instead use WP_Query or get_posts

Comment: I want to use the `date` parameter, for example: `query_posts('date='$date);` If I understand correctly, I cannot use it with WP_Query, or can I?

Comment: query_posts is a wrapper around WP_Query that does horrible things to the main query loop, never use it under any circumstances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use query_posts this will alter your main loop, you can query posts by day 1-31 using [WP-Query();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$day = date('j');
$args = array( 'day' => $day);
$day_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($day_query->have_posts()) :
   while ($day_query->have_posts()) :
       $day_query->the_post();
       //show posts
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```